# WCF DataServices : Entities Deriven from other Entities are inaccessible

Tags: wcf-data-services

I'm new to WCF. I created a data service which is hosted in an empty asp.net application.

It seems that the service doesn't serialize `EntitySets` that derived from other `EntitySets`. It returns the base `EntitySets` correctly but doesn't know the derived `EntitySets` at all.

I'm using EF Code First and am passing the `ObjectContext` as generic parameter of `DataService` class(as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/135586/Using-EF-DbContext-with-WCF-Data-Services))

And my entities look like the following :

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public class People : DomainEntityBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public long ID{get; set;}

    .
    .
    .
}
[DataContract]
public class Employee : Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PersonelCode{ get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ObservableCollection<OrgPost> OrgPosts { get; set; }
}
```

When I test the context in my web browser, it shows `PersonSet` but doesn't show the `EmployeeSet`.

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this article.  Looks like the scenario you are trying with Code First isn't supported.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/8115cf34-4527-4302-9123-0dce010629e0